# Proper way of method swizzling in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, swizzling, method-swizzling

Currently experimenting with method `swizzling` in Objective-C and I have a question. I am trying to understand the proper way to method swizzle and after researching online I stumbled upon this NSHipster post:
http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

In the post the author has some method swizzling sample code. I am looking for someone to better explain to me what the author is doing.. In particular I am confused on the `didAddMethod` logic. Why is the author not just directly `swapping/exchanging` method implementations? My only theory on this is maybe there is some off chance that `viewWillAppear:` is not added to `UIViewController's method` `dispatch_table` yet. Particularly if maybe the category is loaded into memory first before `UIViewController`... Is this the reason why? It seems rather odd? Just looking for some more insight/clarity, thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In particular I am confused on the didAddMethod logic. Why is the author not just directly swapping/exchanging method implementations?

Your confusion is understandable as this logic is not explained clearly.

First ignore the fact that the example is a category on the specific class `UIViewController` and just consider the logic as though the category was on some arbitrary class, let's call that class `TargetClass`.

We'll call the existing method we wish to replace `existingMethod`.

The category, being on `TargetClass`, adds the swizzling method, which we'll call `swizzlingMethod`, to `TargetClass`.

**Important**: Note that the function to get an method, `class_getInstanceMethod`, will find the method in the supplied class *or any of its superclasses*. However the functions `class_addMethod` and `class_replaceMethod` only add/replace methods in the supplied class.

Now there are two cases to consider:

1. `TargetClass` itself directly contains an implementation of `existingMethod`. This is the easy case, all that needs to be done is exchange the implementations of `existingMethod` and `swizzlingMethod`, which can be done with `method_exchangeImplementations`. In the article the call to `class_addMethod` will fail, as there is already and `existingMethod` *directly in* `TargetClass` and the logic results in a call to `method_exchangeImplementations`.
2. `TargetClass` does **not** directly contain an implementation of `existingMethod`, rather that method is provided through inheritance from one of the ancestor classes of `TargetClass`. This is the trickier case. If you simply exchange the implementations of `existingMethod` and `swizzlingMethod` then you would be effecting (instances of) the ancestor class (and in a way which could cause a crash - why is left as an exercise). By calling `class_addMethod` the article's code makes sure there is an `existingMethod` in `TargetClass` - the implementation of which is the original implementation of `swizzlingMethod`. The logic then replaces the implementation of `swizzlingMethod` with the implementation of the ancestor's `existingMethod` (which has no effect on the ancestor).

Still here? I hope that makes sense and hasn't simply sent you cross-eyed!

Another exercise if you're terminally curious: Now you might ask what happens if the ancestor's `existingMethod` implementation contains a call to `super`... if the implementation is now also attached to `swizzlingMethod` in `TargetClass` where will that call to `super` end up? Will it be to implementation in ancestor, which would see the same method implementation executed twice, or to the ancestor's ancestor, as originally intended?

HTH

Comment: Simply amazing answer, this all totally makes sense. Your exercise suggestions are also great and I will drill into those :) You seem to be very knowledgeable about the run-time, I posted another question just now. Would be awesome if you had a chance to take a look (if you have time). Thanks a lot man! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503563/method-swizzling-with-method-setimplementation

Answer (score 1):

`load` is called when a `class` is added in obj-c runtime.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load

So let's say if a `UIViewController` gets added in obj-c runtime which already contains `viewWillAppear:` but you want it to be replaced by another implementation. So first you add a new method `xxxWillAppear:`. 
Now once `xxxWillAppear:` has been added in `ViewController` class, only then you can replace it.

But the author also said :

> For example, let’s say we wanted to track how many times each view controller is presented to a user in an iOS app

so he is trying to demonstrate a case where an app might have many view controllers but you do not want to keep replacing for each `ViewController` the `viewWillAppear:` implementation. Once the point of `viewWillAppear:` has been replaced, then instead of adding, only the exchange will need to be done.

Perhaps source code of Objective C runtime might help :

```
/**********************************************************************
* addMethod
* fixme
* Locking: runtimeLock must be held by the caller
**********************************************************************/
static IMP 
addMethod(Class cls, SEL name, IMP imp, const char *types, BOOL replace)
{
IMP result = nil;

rwlock_assert_writing(&runtimeLock);

assert(types);
assert(cls->isRealized());

method_t *m;
if ((m = getMethodNoSuper_nolock(cls, name))) {
    // already exists
    if (!replace) {
        result = _method_getImplementation(m);
    } else {
        result = _method_setImplementation(cls, m, imp);
    }
} else {
    // fixme optimize
    method_list_t *newlist;
    newlist = (method_list_t *)_calloc_internal(sizeof(*newlist), 1);
    newlist->entsize_NEVER_USE = (uint32_t)sizeof(method_t) | fixed_up_method_list;
    newlist->count = 1;
    newlist->first.name = name;
    newlist->first.types = strdup(types);
    if (!ignoreSelector(name)) {
        newlist->first.imp = imp;
    } else {
        newlist->first.imp = (IMP)&_objc_ignored_method;
    }

    attachMethodLists(cls, &newlist, 1, NO, NO, YES);

    result = nil;
}

return result;
}


BOOL 
class_addMethod(Class cls, SEL name, IMP imp, const char *types)
{
if (!cls) return NO;

rwlock_write(&runtimeLock);
IMP old = addMethod(cls, name, imp, types ?: "", NO);
rwlock_unlock_write(&runtimeLock);
return old ? NO : YES;
}


IMP 
class_replaceMethod(Class cls, SEL name, IMP imp, const char *types)
{
if (!cls) return nil;

rwlock_write(&runtimeLock);
IMP old = addMethod(cls, name, imp, types ?: "", YES);
rwlock_unlock_write(&runtimeLock);
return old;
}
```

You can dig more if you want:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/