# How do I swizzle main bundle with test bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift4, swizzling

I use to swizzle main bundle with test bundle like follow in obj c

```
#import "NSBundle+Bundle.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSBundle (Bundle)

+(void)loadSwizzler {
    static dispatch_once_t once_token;
    dispatch_once(&once_token,  ^{
        Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(mainBundle));
        Method extendedMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(bundleForTestTarget));
        //swizzling mainBundle method with our own custom method
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, extendedMethod);
    });
}

//method for returning app Test target
+(NSBundle *)bundleForTestTarget {
    NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"Philips.AppInfraTests"];

    return bundle;
}

@end
```

But I tried the following for the same in swift

```
     extension Bundle {
  class func swizzle() {
        let originalSelector = #selector(mainBundle)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(testBundle)
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }

    func mainBundle() -> Bundle
    {
        return Bundle.main
    }
    func testBundle() -> Bundle
    {
        return Bundle(for: self.classNamed("swizzler")!)
    }
}
```

But this is throwing some errors "Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to variable 'testBundle'"

could some one help me how do I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer has been tested in Swift 3 & 4 Playground, any other version and YMMV.**

Your Objective-C code swizzles two class methods, your Swift version attempts to swizzle two instance methods - so they are not doing the same thing.

You (probably) cannot swizzle a (pure) Swift function, you can swizzle Objective-C methods, this is due to the differences in how functions/methods are dispatched. So in Swift the replacement function must be marked `@objc` in Swift 4 (it is optional and apparently harmless in Swift 3).

Swift renames `mainBundle` to `main` and surfaces it as a property, so to get the selector for `mainBundle` you need to use `getter: main`.

Combine the above and you get the following Playground code:

```
extension Bundle
{
    class func swizzle()
    {
        let originalSelector = #selector(getter: main)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(testBundle)
        let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, originalSelector)!
        let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, swizzledSelector)!
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }

    @objc class func testBundle() -> Bundle
    {
        // just for testing in Playground
        return Bundle(path: "/Applications/TextEdit.app")!
    }
}

let b = Bundle.main
print(b)
Bundle.swizzle()
let c = Bundle.main
print(c)
```

which prints:

```
NSBundle </Applications/Xcode.app> (not yet loaded)
NSBundle </Applications/TextEdit.app> (not yet loaded)
```

Note that `class_getClassMethod()` returns a `Method?` and the above code forces this *without* any checks, those checks **should exist** in real code!

Finally note that your swizzle code *assumes* `mainBundle` is implemented directly by `NSBundle` and not one of its ancestors, that is probably a safe assumption in this case but is not always. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502215/proper-way-of-method-swizzling-in-objective-c) on doing swizzling safely.

HTH

Comment: To clarify, when used in XCTestCase subclass you can get correct Bundle using `Bundle(for: YouTestCaseClass.self)`