# Assign selector to C function in Objective-C without callback

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, selector

I am attempting a method swizzle in Obj-C but I would like to pass it a pure C function.  This means I need to somehow assign a selector and/or manually build an `objc_method` struct. Maybe somehow leverage `NSInvocation`?

My understanding is that due to the fact that Obj-C is a strict superset of C and therefor fully compatible.

What I have going now:

main.m :

```
#include....

CFStringRef strRet(void) {
    return CFSTR("retString");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        SEL _strRet = sel_registerName("strRet");
        //I also tried: SEL _strRet = NSSelectorFromString(@"strRet");

        Class bundle = objc_getClass("NSBundle");

        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getInstanceMethod(bundle, sel_registerName("anySelector")), 
            class_getInstanceMethod(bundle, sel_registerName("_strRet")
        );
```

I have tried putting the C function inside `@implementation` (which I would like to avoid) and even then it did not work.

Comment: correct me if i understood wrong. You want to pass pure C function ?? in your code snippet no C function shown. can you modify you query little more code ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't swizzle a C function *per se*; swizzling is based on method lookup which goes through method descriptions (which are represented by the `Method` type by the runtime functions) and C functions do not have a method description.

However the implementation of a method is just a C function. Such a C function must take a minimum of two arguments, being the object the method is invoked on (the Objective-C implicit parameter `self`) and the selector (the Objective-C implicit parameter `_cmd`). When you swizzle a method the replacement implementation, a C function, must have exactly the same type as the original – complete with the two implicit arguments – so your `strRet()` would not be suitable as is, you would need to change it to:

```
CFStringRef strRet(NSObject *self, CMD sel, void)
{
   return CFSTR("retString");
}
```

So you have three main choices:

1. The easiest way is to define a method whose body is your "pure" C function, then swizzle the recommended way (taking care to handle inheritance correctly, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502215/proper-way-of-method-swizzling-in-objective-c/34503380#34503380)).
2. If you really want to write a C function and that C function **does not** need to call the original implementation of the method then:

   (a) You need to convert your C function into one which can be used as a method implementation. You can:

   - If you are writing/have the source of the C function you simply define it to take the two implicit arguments as above. Take the address of this function and cast it to `IMP`, which is just a `typedef` for a C function pointer of the appropriate type, for use below.
   - If you are using a C function whose definition you cannot change then you can do one of:

     - Write a C wrapper function which takes the extra arguments, ignores them and calls your target C function. Take the address of this wrapper function and cast it to `IMP` for use below.
     - Wrap the call to your C function in a *block* and use [`imp_implementationWithBlock()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime) to produce an `IMP` value from it. You can read [this article](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/03/17/ios-4-3-imp_implementationwithblock/) for a description of using `imp_implementationWithBlock()`.

   (b) use `method_setImplementation()` to set the implementation to the `IMP` value you produced in (a).
3. If you really want to write a C function and that C function **does** need to call the original implementation of the method then you will need to add a method to your class whose implementation is your C function – modified/wrapped as in (2), then swizzle your added method with your original method as under (1) so that the original implementation is still available as a method. To add a method you use `class_addMethod()`

HTH

Comment: You can also use imp_implementationWithBlock().  It makes it easy to wrap a c function in a block that can be plugged in as a method in the runtime.

Comment: @bbum - Duh, forgot that one. Edited the answer to include it as an option. Thanks.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the resources!

Answer (score 2):

The key here is finding a mechanism that maps between the function pointer and your context. The simplest way to do that is by generating a new function pointer. You can use imp_implementationWithBlock(), [MABlockClosure](https://github.com/mikeash/MABlockClosure), or roll your own.

The simplest mechanism to create a new function pointer I've found is to remap the entire function to a new address space. The new resulting address can be used as a key to the required data.

```
#import <mach/mach_init.h>
#import <mach/vm_map.h>

void *remap_address(void* address, int page_count)
{
    vm_address_t source_address = (vm_address_t) address;
    vm_address_t source_page = source_address & ~PAGE_MASK;

    vm_address_t destination_page = 0;
    vm_prot_t cur_prot;
    vm_prot_t max_prot;
    kern_return_t status = vm_remap(mach_task_self(),
                                &destination_page,
                                PAGE_SIZE*(page_count ? page_count : 4),
                                0,
                                VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE,
                                mach_task_self(),
                                source_page,
                                FALSE,
                                &cur_prot,
                                &max_prot,
                                VM_INHERIT_NONE);

    if (status != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    vm_address_t destination_address = destination_page | (source_address & PAGE_MASK);

    return (void*) destination_address;
}
```

Note that `page_count` should be large enough to contain all of your original function. Also, remember to handle pages that aren't required anymore and note that it takes a lot more memory per invocation than [MABlockClosure](https://github.com/mikeash/MABlockClosure).

(Tested on iOS)